# Empty platforms folder after cmd prompting [Phonegap] Attempting PhoneGap local run for android

Tags: android, cordova, cmd, sencha-touch

I have designed some pages with sencha touch, my cmd version is 5.0.324 and the phonegap version that I'm using is `3.5.0-0.21.14`.

The problem that I'm currently facing is after the cmd prompts:

```
[Phonegap] Attempting PhoneGap local run for android
```

Which only stay for a second. When I go to the platforms folder inside the phonegap folder I do not see any folder or file.

I've installed android sdk manager.
I've installed jre version 7, node version 0.10.29.
I've also installed all other required installs and I have also changed the path of android folder in `.bashrc`, but I don seem to get the apk.

Comment: When are you getting this prompt?

Comment: @SujataChanda im getting this message after i run the  sencha app build -run native command...